# Creating a closure for std::function

Tags: c++, c++11, std-function

I am not sure if I am using the exact terminology , But  I'll try to be as descriptive as possible to clear out any confusion .

Suppose I have an std::function variable

```
std::function<void(int)>  callback ;
```

Due to some reasons beyond my scope , I cannot change the function prototype.
I receive the std::function variable at some point in my code and I have to call it.Something like this :

```
int a = 10 // just an example value
callback(a);
```

Now I have another variable . Let's name it id .

```
int id = rand(); // Let us assume that rand here generates a random variable
int a = 10 // just an example value
callback(a);
```

I want id to be accessible inside the callback i.e I am looking for some form of closure .
Is there any way to do it without making the `id` static/global.

Comment: No .....................

Comment: Not possible, `id` could be captured by `callback` where the callback is created, but as you said, it is beyond  your scope :)

Comment: If the callback is a part of a class you can control. You could make a `set_id()` function and store the variable in the class.

Comment: Not enough context. I'm suspecting that lambda which you are passing to `callback` should capture this `id`, but your question is incomplete and misleading. It would be best if you read some C++ book section about lamdas or at least provide more context of your problem.

Comment: If you're given `callback` by somebody else, what did you expect it to do with a variable its author didn't know about? Even if you could get that variable captured?

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings  . I have a preprocessor directive (#define function )that the callback is using for logging ..  . I can change the directive  to include id (if available in the scope) in the logs . That was my plan

Comment: That sounds like a crucial detail that should not have been left out of your question. Present a [mcve] please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot do that.

`callback` has no state unless it was designed to have state (which it wasn't).

This shouldn't matter, though: if you have no control over the `callback`, then it already does not want to use your variable `id`. And if you *do* have control over it, then you can simply replace it with a lambda that does capture the variable and do whatever you want to do with it.

Comment: Even if I add a lambda to capture id [id](int){ // do something} , id would still not be in the scope where the  lambda would be declared . That would give an compilation error

Comment: @UchihaItachi I meant replace it locally. i.e. call some other thing than `callback`. It's not really clear what your constraints are and why.

Answer (score 0):

You can *change* the `std::function`:

```
std::function<void(int)> callback;
int id = rand();
callback = [=](int a){callback(a*id);};
```

I'm using a lambda here to create a new unnamed function. This takes a copy `[=]` of `id` and `callback` (the one you got), and then I assign the lambda back to the original `callback`.

Note that this also copies `id`. The example is so limited that I cannot be sure that `id`'s lifetime is long enough. You can capture by reference, but as with all references in C++ you need to be careful of the lifetime of the referenced object.